Wasserstein distance to assess the degree of normality
The Wasserstein distance between two probability measures with quantile functions $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$ is given by
\begin{align}
W(F,G) = \int_{[0,1]} |F^{-1}(t) - G^{-1}(t)|dt
\end{align}
Now let's imagine that I have $k$ distributions $F_1, ..., F_k$ and would like to compare the degree of normality between them by the means of the Wasserstein distance $W_i(F_i, G), i = 1,...,k$ where $G \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$. In order to compare $W_i$ I need to assure that the range $[a,b] \ni W_i$ is exactly the same for each $W_i$ and as far as I know, the condition for that is that each pair $(F_i, G)$ has the same support $[c,d]$. However, there is a problem: if I rescale the distribution $F_i$ so that it has the same support as $G$, then the empirical means for $F_i$ and $G$ aren't equal and so are not the variances. If I, on the other hand, assure that the first two moments of $F_i$ and $G$ are equal, then $\operatorname{supp}(F_i) \neq \operatorname{supp}(G)$, especially if $F_i$ is highly skewed and thus the distances aren't comparable. Is there any way to make it work?

Won't such a comparison call out a totally normal $F_i$ as being very distant from $G$ if $\mu_i$ greatly differs from $\mu$ and/or $\sigma_i$ greatly differs from $\sigma?$ $//$ If The $F_i$ do not have support across all of $\mathbb R$, you might find difficulties in trying to get them to have the same support as a Gaussian.
